# Need _layout to display data set from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I maybe have backed myself into a wall here but anyways;

I want my layoutpage to show my some information that is retrived from the Account-controller. I also wanted to do it the "right" way without the ViewBag so i made a Controllerand Datamodel for it.

Model;

```
   public class Culture
    {
        public string culture { get; set; }
    }
```

controller;

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Culture {  "foo" };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

View;

```
@model PlayGround.Models.Culture
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>@Model.culture</h2>
```

And then i just call it from the _Layout

```
    @Html.Action("index", "Culture")
```

This works fine but the problem i want to set "foo" in a function (account-controller) and i want that data to stay put until something else is told to it... So the question is quite stupid but i cant get my head around it, How do i set The model data in a nice way from another controller? Or im a way off target?

Comment: You can use ViewBag there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Session` to store the culture information for that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! You mean in the Session-Cookie?

Comment: Not the cookie per se, but the `Session` object.

Comment: Okey, i will look into that. Thanks! :) On a footnote, is there any nice way make controllers share data?